# Does 'position()' have to be explicitly included in this Xpath?

Tags: position, xpath-2.0

This returns all the first 'nd's as expected

```
select="osm/way/nd[1]"
```

This returns all the lasts:

```
select="osm/way/nd[last()]"
```

This returns both:

```
select="osm/way/nd[position() = 1 or position() = last()]"
```

Is there a syntax to remove position() function?
Something like this, but works?

```
select="osm/way/nd[[1] or [last()]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been some debate about allowing a new syntax to select a range https://github.com/qt4cg/qtspecs/issues/50#issuecomment-799228627 e.g. `osm/way/nd[#1,last()]` might work in a future XPath 4 but currently it is all up in the air of a lot of debate and questionable whether a new operator is helpful instead of doing `osm/way/nd[position() = (1, last())]`.

Comment: Thanks, that clears some confusion. My PoV - Fewer syntax errors from less typing.